# HABTM and Naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been racking my head around a rails issue for a while and wanted to verify my findings. I was trying to get the Has_and_belongs_to_many relationship working, but couldn't connect my two classes, auctionItem and category. First of all, here was my migration file and the two classes before solving the issue:

Migration file:

```
class AuctionItemsCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table 'auction_items_categories', :id=>false do |t|
      t.reference :auctionItem_id
      t.references :category_id 
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'auction_items_categories'
  end
end
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :auction_items
end
```

auction_item.rb

```
class AuctionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

After creating an instance of AuctionItem, I tried

```
auction_item = AuctionItem.last
auction_item.categories
```

...and got the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `categories' for #<AuctionItem:0x0000010521b870>
```

After some research, I found adding the specific class to the has_and_belongs_to_many helped:

Category Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :auction_items , :class_name => 'AuctionItem'
```

auction_item Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories , :class_name => 'Category'
```

This solved that issue and I was able to access the categories table. I went on to try to append a category to the auction item:

```
auction_item.categories << category
```

I then got received the following error:

```
SELECT "auction_items".* FROM "auction_items" INNER JOIN "auction_items_categories" ON "auction_items"."id" = "auction_items_categories"."auction_item_id" WHERE "auction_items_categories"."category_id" = 2
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: auction_items_categories.auction_item_id: SELECT "auction_items".* FROM "auction_items" INNER JOIN "auction_items_categories" ON "auction_items"."id" = "auction_items_categories"."auction_item_id" WHERE "auction_items_categories"."category_id" = 2
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: auction_items_categories.auction_item_id: SELECT "auction_items".* FROM "auction_items" INNER JOIN "auction_items_categories" ON "auction_items"."id" = "auction_items_categories"."auction_item_id" WHERE "auction_items_categories"."category_id" = 2
```

If you notice, the query is trying to get auction_item.id rather than AuctionItem.id. To get the connection to work, I had to change my migration file to the following:

```
class AuctionItemsCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table 'auction_items_categories', :id=>false do |t|
      t.integer :auction_item_id
      t.integer :category_id 
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'auction_items_categories'
  end
end
```

**So long story short/TL DR version:** For me, it seems that when naming your class with multiple words and using camel case, rails does not singularize your pluralized class name back to it's original state if it has an underscore. So for example, my class name was AuctionItem which became auction_items for the model. Rather than search for **auctionitem.id**, the sql call that was looked for was **auction_item.id**, which is the singularize version of auction_items. Why didn't it search for auctionitem.id? In the future, when I am making association tables with multi word classes, do I use the singular underscore id version of the model name?

Answer (score 1):

Your original migration was incorrect. It should have been as follows:

```
class AuctionItemsCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration    
  def up
    create_table 'auction_items_categories', :id => false do |t|
      t.references :auction_item
      t.references :category
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'auction_items_categories'
  end
end
```

You should specify the symbolized model name when using references.